# htaccess not working for directory redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have directory my-site.com/m/ and it contain so many sub-folder so i want internal redirect for sub-folder to my-site.com/m/req="rest-path-of-directory"

ex
my-site.com/m/article/pc to my-site.com/m/?req=article/pc

For this I use the code below but something is wrong, it is not working for me.

My .htaccess file is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/m/([A-Za-z0-9\/]*)/?$    http://www.localhost/m/index.php?req=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Remove the Leading slash from RewritePattern.

Comment: thanks but it is not case ;i already try so many combination possible which one of you suggest but it was not working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/m/([A-Za-z0-9\/]*)$    http://www.localhost/m/index.php?req=$1    [L]
```

I think the /? outside your capture group brackets is never being matched, as all the / characters are being captured inside your `([A-Za-z0-9\/]*)` expression.

Comment: you are right \? never match and i think it not effect the pattern its optional

Answer (score 0):

For internal redirection you need to remove the hostname and scheme from the Rewrite target

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^m/([A-Za-z0-9\/]*)/?$ /m/index.php?req=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks you but i also try as you suggest it is even not external redirecting

Comment: it is .htaccess file and module is on in config file